# Elevation accuracy of dual band RTK GNSS module? (ZED-F9P)

Tags: gnss

Does anyone know the accuracy of height given from the ublox F9P dual band GNSS module in RTK mode?  Or any dual band RTK GNSS module in general?

The website says up to 1 cm accuracy but I don't know if that is only for long/lat or for height as well.

website of product:
https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/zed-f9p-module

Comment: RTK can give sub-centimetre relative accuracy in height and in lat/lon between two different stations (that are close enough), but only 10s of metres absolute height accuracy for a single station, whereas lat/lon absolute will be an order of magnitude better.

Comment: @Neil_UK by single station you are not talking about RTK mode right?  RTK is minimum rover + base?

Comment: RTK only offers accuracy enhancement between two stations. Some modes allow you multiple references for increased accuracy. Any single station taken by itself, even if RTK'ing with another station, will not have enhanced absolute accuracy, unless the position of the other station is known absolutely. I think your question was more about height, versus lat/lon. The accuracy improvement is as good on height as it is on lat/lon. That contrasts to absolute, where lat/lon is an order of magnitude better than height.

Comment: Ok just to clarify "That contrasts to absolute" by absolute you are talking about any station taken by iteself?

Comment: Datasheet says 0.01m = 1cm of vertical in any of the RTK modes.  This is relative to the other station as mentioned by @Neil_UK.  The absolute accuracy is relative to the surveyed location of the other station or general GPS accuracy which is better than 10m vertical or 1m horizontal if the other site is not surveyed.